# I tried to connect mysql8.0.32 to the spring boot project in eclipse after I tried to run spring boot main class but its showing some error

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

**Application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
#hibernate properties 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBdialect
#create,create-drop
spring.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**springprojectmain.java**

```java
packagePcom.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StringProject1Application {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(StringProject1Application.class, args);
      }

}
```

I got below error:

```
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBdialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBdialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBdialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name   'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.
```

I tried to connect mysql8.0.32 to the spring boot project in eclipse after I tried to run spring boot main class but its showing some error in application properties file at `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBdialect`.

Comment: Can you add your Pom to the question and tidy the formatting of the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBdialect
```

Replace `MySQL5InnoDBdialect` with `MySQL5Dialect`.

Comment: I was facing similar issue this worked perfectly for me.
Thanks